# SVG.js line marker-mid

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

im trying to put the marker-mid on the line element, im using SVG.js. For example im using this code:

```
var draw = SVG('yourdivid');
var line = draw.line( 100, 100, 0, 0).move(20, 20); 
line.stroke({ color: '#000', width: 2};
```

now how can i put the marker at the mid of this line using the marker-mid?
i read the doc of svg.js and also this" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/marker-mid#Examples" 
they say that you can use the marker-mid element also with the line, i know that this marker works with the path element, but i need to use it with a line, can you help me please? 
thank you for your help

Comment: There's no mid there, a line has a beginning and an end only

Comment: "mid" refers to the middle points of a multi-segment path. Ie. the second to the second-to-last points. Since a `<line>` has only a start and an end point, there are no mid points to place markers on.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so how can i solve this problem? coz im using svg.draw.js to draw the line and then i need a mid-marker on it, there are any other way to make it?

Answer (score 1):

You could just work out the mid point of the line yourself and draw a circle at that point.

```
var start = [100, 100];
var end = [0, 0];

function midPoint(start, end) {
    return [
          (start[0] + end[0]) / 2,
          (start[1] + end[1]) / 2
    ];
}

var lineGroup = svg.group();
lineGroup.line(start[0][0], start[0][1], end[0][0], end[0][1]);

var dot = lineGroup.circle(3);
var mid = midPoint(start, end);
dot.cx(mid[0]);
dot.cy(mid[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`marker-mid` does not work on lines. To have start and end markers, this code would do it:

```
var draw = SVG('yourdivid');

draw.line( 100, 100, 0, 0)
    .move(20, 20)
    .stroke({ color: '#000', width: 2})
    .marker('start', 10, 10, function(add){
        add.circle(10).center(5,5) 
    })
```

However, to have markers at the mid of a line see p0wdr.com's answer

Comment: As wrote @Paul LeBeau in the above comment; '"mid" refers to the middle points of a multi-segment path ... Since a <line> has only a start and an end point, there are no mid points to place markers on'